# User input not correctly being added to a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to specify my list type by pressing -1
then I want to add numbers to the numbers list
then I want to add those numbers up when I press "F"

For some reason it doesn't listen to me and adds F to the list which gives me an error

thank you in advance.

```py
numbers =[]
ListType = int(input())
if ListType < 0:
    while True :
        if input()!= "F":
            value = input()
            numbers.append(value)
        else:
            print(sum(numbers))
```

Comment: Could you fix your indentations around the first ```if``` statement. I'm guessing you would move it backwards, but please clarify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues here:

1. You are calling `input()` in `while` loop due to which the loop will only check the condition with the odd inputs and won't append that in the list, thus, half of the inputs will be ignored.
2. `sum()` require a **numeric** list. But since values taken from `input()` aren't type-casted, therefore, are appended as string. You can confirm this by using `print(type(numbers[0]))` somewhere in the code.

Therefore, after correcting these issues, your code would look like:

```
numbers =[]
ListType = int(input())
if ListType < 0:
    while True:
        value = input()
        if value != "F":
            numbers.append(int(value))
        else:
            print(sum(numbers))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works in Pycharm but when i try to make it go through my uni's exercice verifier i get this error : EOFError: EOF when reading a line. Any ideas?

Comment: @MaxBouzari What is the input format in that verifier?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean? i just copy and past from pycharm to the website in a little box and it verifies is automatically